# custom tabs in media uploader

Tags: admin, uploads, media, thickbox, tabs

I've managed to add a custom tab to the media uploader, but for some reason it doesn't come with the same layout - it doesn't load the media-uploader-header that contain all the other tabs:

```
  add_filter('media_upload_tabs', 'my_media_upload_tabs_filter');

function my_media_upload_tabs_filter($tabs) {
        unset($tabs["type_url"]);
        unset($tabs['library']);
        $newtab = array('ell_insert_gmap_tab' => __('Google Map','insertgmap'));

        return array_merge($tabs,$newtab);
}

add_action('media_upload_ell_insert_gmap_tab', 'media_upload_ell_gmap_tab');

function media_upload_ell_gmap_tab() {
    return wp_iframe('media_upload_ell_gmap_form', $errors );
}

function media_upload_ell_gmap_form() {
    ?>
    <h2>HTML Form</h2>

<?php
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found it. 
in the automattic SVN for [media.php](http://svn.automattic.com/wordpress/trunk/wp-admin/includes/media.php) i found the media_upload_header() function, and the only thing left to do is to echo it in the last function:

```
function media_upload_ell_gmap_form() {
    echo media_upload_header();
    ?>
    <h2>HTML Form</h2>

<?php
}
```

that's it.

Comment: and [this](http://axcoto.com/blog/article/307) also works.