# send information from the thickbox image uploader second tab

Tags: admin, uploads, media, theme-options, thickbox

in this [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11357/custom-tabs-in-media-uploader) i've found how to create a custom tab at the image uploader.

this is the code:

```
add_filter('media_upload_tabs', 'my_media_upload_tabs_filter');

function my_media_upload_tabs_filter($tabs) {
        unset($tabs["type_url"]);
        unset($tabs['library']);
        $newtab = array('ell_insert_gmap_tab' => __('Google Map','insertgmap'));

        return array_merge($tabs,$newtab);
}

add_action('media_upload_ell_insert_gmap_tab', 'media_upload_ell_gmap_tab');

function media_upload_ell_gmap_tab() {
    return wp_iframe('media_upload_ell_gmap_form', $errors );
}

function media_upload_ell_gmap_form() {
    ?>
    echo media_upload_header();
    ?>
    <h2>HTML Form</h2>

<?php
}
```

Now i want to use that tab for image choosing function. so i modified the code inside the tab into this:

```
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">
            <h3 class="media-title">Choose Background:</h3>
            Alternatively, you can choose one of these background images:<br/>
            <img style="float:left; margin:15px; cursor:pointer" id="background-Green-stripes" src="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/wp-content/themes/mytheme/images/background-Green-stripes-thumb.jpg">
<a class="button choice_button" style="float:left; display:block" id="image 1">choose this</a>
            <img style="float:left; margin:15px; cursor:pointer" id="background-Pail-pink-squares.jpg" src="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/wp-content/themes/mytheme/images/background-Pail-pink-squares-thumb.jpg">
<a class="button choice_button" style="float:left; display:block" id="image 2">choose this</a>
            <img style="float:left; margin:15px; cursor:pointer" id="background-Purple-wall.jpg" src="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/wp-content/themes/mytheme/images/background-Purple-wall-thumb.jpg">
    <a class="button choice_button" style="float:left; display:block" id="image 3">choose this</a>
        </form>
```

and tried to get the html from the "window.send_to_editor" but didn't knew how... 
can any body help? i'm lost here...

Comment: i found out that i need some how to produce the "insert to post" button... how should i do this? someone?

Comment: Not necessarily, take a look at the send to editor function at the top of `wp-admin/js/media-upload.dev.js`, can you not just call that? Or look at what that function does, and pull what you need from it..

Comment: I don't know how to use it with a new tab in the media-uploader... i don't know how to send information back to the "html" var inside send_to_editor with a simple button...

Comment: i also tried playing with the form action, like this: `function media_upload_ell_gmap_form() {
 echo media_upload_header();
 ?>

 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="http://www.mimi.me/wp-admin/media-upload.php?type=image&amp;tab=insert_choose_background&amp;post_id=0&amp;mysetting=myvalue">
  <h3 class="media-title">Choose Background:</h3>
 <input name="send" id="send" class="button" value="Insert into Post" type="submit">
 </form> 
<?php
}`  but i got nothing... any one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i decided that for me, i can settle for changing an input field on the top.parent for it to be used with the native options. i used this for the function of the iframe tab:

```
function media_upload_choosebackground_form() {
     media_upload_header();
    ?>
    <h3 class="media-title">HTML Form</h3>
        <img src="http://www.mimi.me/wp-content/themes/mimi.me_regular_sites/images/background-Green-stripes-thumb.jpg" style="cursor:pointer; float:left; margin:10px 0 0 10px" id="greenstripes" title="Green Stripes" />
        <img src="http://www.mimi.me/wp-content/themes/mimi.me_regular_sites/images/background-Pail-pink-squares-thumb.jpg" style="cursor:pointer; float:left; margin:10px 0 0 10px" id="Pailpinksquares" title="Pail pink squares" />
        <img src="http://www.mimi.me/wp-content/themes/mimi.me_regular_sites/images/background-Purple-wall-thumb.jpg" style="cursor:pointer; float:left; margin:10px 0 0 10px" id="Purplewall" title="Purple wall" />
<?php
}
```

and this as the click event for every image:

```
jQuery('#Purplewall').click(function() {
        imgurl = "http://www.mimi.me/wp-content/themes/mimi.me_regular_sites/images/background-Purple-wall-thumb.jpg";
        $("#MoobBackgroundUpload", top.document).val(imgurl);
        $("#MoobBackgroundUploadButtonImg", top.document).attr('src', imgurl);
        parent.tb_remove();
    });
```

and what i've got is a second tab with an image picker, and that what i wanted in the first place. 
good for me!